# taking screenshot of real IOS device via macbook command line

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot

I am looking for a way to automate the taking of screenshots of ios devices. I read about xcrun but that only works on iphone simulators. In android, there is android ADB which allows the sending of instruction to android device via command line.

Is there any tool / library to help me achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool [Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/), I haven't tried it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to write a iOS UI test which captures Screen Shot of your app
- Use Fastlane to run those test and store it.

Refer [this blog](https://medium.com/@juli1quere/automate-ios-screenshots-with-fastlane-b4fd90ef425b) for detailed explanation.

Comment: fastlane only allows me to take screenshots of my own app and not screenshots in general right ?